# how to find percentage

Tags: c#

I want to show risk ratio in my application.

I want to get this value in percent for example

let a = 100, b = 50;

I want to show the value in percentage value = a - b;
 = 50;

I want to show this in percentage.

any suggestions.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Percentages are just real numbers between 0 and 1, multiplied by 100.

Comment: percentage of what?! what exactly are the values? clarify the question first.

Comment: Are you wanting the maths or the code? What code do you already have?

Comment: do you want to show a percentage sign after that value? what have you tried so far? Show us some code

Comment: It's not because a - b = 50 that b is 50% of a but because b/a = 0.5

Comment: Use Google to get a grip of percentage and then get back here when you have some code and ask specific questions!

Comment: string buy = listviewTargets.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
                    string target1 = listviewTargets.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
                    Double purchases = Convert.ToDouble(buy);
                    Double visitors = Convert.ToDouble(target1);
                    double c = ((double)purchases / visitors) * 100;
                    MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:0%}",c));` as your last line and omit the `*100` in the second to last line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let percentage=100*(a-b)/a
```

and maybe you will want to round it

Comment: Since when is that C#?

Comment: Is inversed! use " int percentage=100-(100*(a-b)/a) " instead

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question properly,

if a=total and b is the part

then b/a*100 = the percentage taken

```
 Double a = 100;
 Double b = 50;
 Double percentage = (b/a*100);

 // to output the result
 Labelcontrol.Text = percentage.ToString();

 // or if just a plain c# app you can send it to the console
 Console.WriteLine(percentage.ToString());
```

Update: I have realised you may want the other way around where you want the percentage left once you remove the value. In that case the calculation line is simply updated to:

```
 Double percentage = 100*(a-b)/a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using string.format to format the result (C#, as you've tagged the question with)

```
int a = 100, b = 50;
double p = (double)(a - b) / a;
string s = string.Format("Result is {0:0.0%}", p);
```